# Sequelize magic functions not found

Tags: sequelize.js

I have been trying to use magic functions but it's not found.

I haven't been using an alias on the model but after I failed to find the magic functions by assuming the name is based on the model names I used to create them, I tried to add alias to my models, still, the magic functions are not found which I thought they are to be based on the aliases.

Now I am kinda lost. How can I inspect the instance of the model to check if the magic functions are what?

My model name is not simple words. One is DaUser (table is da_users). Another one is DaOrganization(table is da_organizations). So I tried to create a Many to Many relationship and I created a new model DaUserOrg with these two relationship set.

```
DaUser.belongsToMany(DaOrganization, {
    through: DaUserOrg,
    as: { singular: 'da_organization', plural: 'da_organizations' },
    foreignKey: 'da_user_id',
    otherKey: 'da_organization_id'
});

DaOrganization.belongsToMany(DaUser, {
    through: DaUserOrg,
    as: { singular: 'da_user', plural: 'da_users' },
    foreignKey: 'da_organization_id',
    otherKey: 'da_user_id'
});
```

Before, there is only `through`. I added the rest because magic functions are not to be found.

I tried "addDaOrganizations" "setDaOrganizations" "addDaOrganization" .. all not found.

Because I am in this fairly big code base. Adding alias is a big move. I have to update all the places where the Organization is included because sequelize requires to use "as" when you include a model with alias. This gives such headache.

Any idea why this is not working for me?

I think I will try using simple English word for alias later on but it feels I really just missed something very basic here.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/91416e3b4bcda28b4f862eb3862f70472e66d57a/lib/associations/belongs-to-many.js#L212

Finally I get it to work by checking the source code of Sequelize.

I also removed alias which was giving me more work to update all the existing code.

So like I have imagined, it was not dealing with CamelCase conversion of English words more than one syllables. So the magic function in my case is

`addDa_organizations`
`setDa_organizations`

I suppose adding alias should work so you can use simple words to refer to your entities.

Comment: Is possible to change the ID naming when calling this magic functions?

Comment: Not sure what you mean "ID naming". The magic function is based on your model definitions. So all the foreign keys etc are wired up based on that

Comment: i setup my foreign key as skill_id in migrations, in my models and in my associate function... but somehow when using this magic functions Sequelize ignores it and uses as skillId, the default structure from Sequelize

Comment: ok. I never customized foreign key. always used what sequealize creates by defaut. Well, in those places check you have written {foreignKey, sourceKey}, belongsToMany(xxx, { through: xxx}) has the "through" thing. Then it might be a bug on sequelize side

Comment: the though thing is for the table names right? i always using my foreignKey on my belongTo belongsToMany using my custom foreignkeys

Comment: through: model . ex. DaOrganization.belongsToMany(DaServer, {
    through: DaServerOrg
});

Comment: yeah, i did that, and the through i place my models name, right now im having to use exclude to remove the "ghost default field" the sequelize is trying to input, so im my case im using skill_id and sequelize is trying to call skillId when i use FindAll()